# Чтение спецсимволов из файла

Tags: c#

Как сделать, чтобы StreamReader при чтении текстового файла .txt определял спецсимволы и получалось:

Блаблабла \r\n блаблабла

=

Блаблабла
блаблабла

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Пробовал добавлять в код куски, вроде

```
if (input /*переменная вида StreamReader*/ = "\r\n") {...}
```

Но ничего толкового это не дало, как бы ни выворачивался, всё равно не хочет воспринимать символы. 
UPD: В общем, объясню: текстовый файл из 5 строк. Первая строка - заголовок. Остальные семь - текст. Строки читаются, и каждая помещается в свой label на форме. Заголовок - строка длинная, в форме не умещается. Чтобы уместить её, я решил использовать спецсимволы (дабы делать перенос).

Comment: Ты делаешь что-то не то.

Comment: А зачем вам? Что за формат вы пытаетесь прочитать?

Comment: Я делаю то, что поставил себе задачей сделать. Пока язык для меня новый, делаю всякую лабуду в надежде на то, что полученные знания позже пригодятся.

Comment: @bravo4827: А какая конкретная задача? Что за странный формат у вас?

Comment: @VladD формат обычный, блокнотовский .txt. А задачу я описал. Это не прикладная программа, просто пробник, я учусь работать со StreamReader'ом и форматом string. Ну, и с формами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `StreamReader` есть великолепный метод, который позволяет читать построчно

```
StreamReader.ReadLine()
```

Использовать так:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath)) 
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

на выходе будет нужный вам результат

**UPD:** После уточнения топикстартера добавлю немного кода

```
var strArr = new List<string>();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath)) 
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        strArr.Add(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}

var result = string.Join("\r\n",strArr);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно разделять текст именно при помощи спецсимволов, если, конечно, такое возможно. Прошу прощения, нужно было сразу конкретизировать. про метод ReadLine знаю, как раз его для чтения файла и использую

Comment: пожалуй вам надо почитать MSDN и как работает метод ReadLine(). Если вы пишите потом еще куда-то, то используйте метод WriteLine() подходящего для вас объекта, каждая строка в этом случае будет отделена спец-символами

Comment: @bravo4827 _"про метод ReadLine знаю, как раз его для чтения файла и использую"_  -- а какой смысл читать строку до `\r\n` и позже добавлять `\r\n`?

Comment: А как ещё разделить строку на две строки (как бы абсурдно это ни звучало)?

Comment: @Dmitry, спасибо, это как раз то, что я пытался сделать. Я не знал, что существует такой метод для типа string, и поэтому застопорился на этом.

Comment: @bravo4827 как я понял из вопроса, вам надо прочесть целиком весь текст-- см. File.ReadAllText, а если построчно -- см. File.ReadAllLines. но если файл огромный -- см. File.ReadLines

Answer (score 2):

```
var sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
    var ch = sr.Read();
    switch (ch) {
        case 10: Console.Write("\\n"); break;
        case 13: Console.Write("\\r"); break;
        default: Console.Write((char)ch); break;
    }
}
sr.Close();
```

---

Но лучше вынести чтение в отдельный метод, который возвращает IEnumerable. Это позволит использовать LINQ.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

var chars = Read(@"c:\temp\test.txt").Select(ch => (char)ch);
foreach (var ch in chars)
    Console.Write(ch);

IEnumerable<int> Read(string path) {
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            yield return sr.Read();
}
```